French movie about Paris catacombs
I saw this in the 90s but the movie is probably older, maybe as old as the 1970s. 
It was about someone noticing wine and/or cheese disappearing from his wine cellar in the basement of his house. It turns out there is a secret passage that connected his basement to the sprawling Paris catacombs. The guy follow the passage trying to find where it leads and is "captured" by a band of people who live underneath the city. It turns out they regularly steal food/wine and throw parties.
At the end the police shows up and everyone runs away.
It's not a horror movie, more of a comedy than anything. 

Possibly Les Gaspards, a French movie from 1974 featuring Michel Serrault, Philippe Noiret and a young Gérard Depardieu. The English title is "The Holes". It's a comedy about parties in the Paris underground. If you speak French.
Synopsis:

A group of misfits who've given up on humanity have decided to dwell below the pavement. The group has its own hierarchy, of course, and soon the conditions that drove them underground begin to manifest themselves without the influences of the Outside World. They start to kidnap people...

Here are some scenes from the movie:




could be! Looks very promising.

Why the downvote?
